# Cloud Vision and Cloud Functions return empty response

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I am listening to changes in my storage bucket to detect faces in images. And log the results out.

my function is as follows

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import vision from "@google-cloud/vision";
import path = require('path');

const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

export const CheckFace = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (image) => {
  try {
    if(image == null) return;
    const imageID = image.name;
    const contentType = image?.contentType;
    if(!contentType?.startsWith('image/')) return;
    const userID = imageID.includes(".")? path.basename(imageID).split(".")[0]:imageID;
    console.log(userID);
    
    const [result] = await client.faceDetection(`gs://${image.bucket}/${imageID}`);
    const faces = result.faceAnnotations;

    console.log(result)
    console.log(faces)
    
    if(faces == undefined || faces == null || faces.length < 0){
      console.log("noFace");
      return;
    }else if(faces.length > 1){
      console.log("more than 1");
      return;
    }else if(faces.length == 1){
      console.log("one face")
      return;
    }else{
      console.log("error")
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
});
```

All I get is

```
{ 
        faceAnnotations: [],
        landmarkAnnotations: [],
        logoAnnotations: [],
        labelAnnotations: [],
        textAnnotations: [],
        safeSearchAnnotation: null,     
        imagePropertiesAnnotation: null,    
        error: null,
        cropHintsAnnotation: null,     
        fullTextAnnotation: null,     
        webDetection: null 
   }
```

What could I be doing wrong ?
I have tried adding a service account but I still get the same error.
Do I need a service account for this or does the firebase admin take care of it

Comment: Are you sure this is proper code? I have tried to deploy this but it shows many errors during deployment. Have you tried to test it locally?

Comment: @vitooh It's a cloud function. Haven't deployed it locally. What errors is it showing ?

Comment: I mean I tried to deploy in the firebase, but every cloud function should be tested locally somehow. I get some errors like: `error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'`....

Comment: @vitooh are you using typescript ?

Comment: Yep, but just checked that in JS it shows: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.  What do you have in `package.json`?